# Sci-Fi novel (series?) about shapeshifting killer whales

Tags: story-identification, shape-shifter

I remember reading a book about 25 years ago (so around 1990?) which featured shapeshifting killer whales as the antagonists.

- It had a techno-fantasy feel to it, with people having body-phones tattooed on their skin
- (plot point: one of the protagonists had lost his phone when he suffered a skin injury)
- The Orcas could take human form
- I think it was a series with multiple books, pretty sure I only read the second one
- It was in my primary school (elementary school) library
- The protagonists were surfers maybe? I think it was set either in Queensland Australia, or California.
- Might have had a conservationalist/Eco-warrior theme; "save the environment before it destroys us" kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure this is "[Above the Lower Sky](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/981842.Above_the_Lower_Sky?from_search=true)" by Tom Deitz.

[image]

The novel focuses on selkies and the aforementioned shape-shifting killer whales. There are also two dolphin minor characters that tie into the techno-futurist subplot that you've mentioned above. The novel is part of a series but its the first, not the second book in the duet. The second novel is "[Demons in the Green](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/981844.The_Demons_in_the_Green)".

[image]

Comment: That is certainly pinging some synapses! I’ll endeavour to track down a copy and report back then.

Comment: best of luck! its not particularly hard to find, but it has been out of print for a while